# Python function as an argument for a R function using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I wrote a function in Python 2.7:

```
# Python #
def function_py(par):
    #something happens
    return(value)
```

and I want to use this function as an argument for another function in R. More precisely, I want to perform to compute the Sobol' indices using the following function:

```
# R #
library('sensitivity')
sobol(function_py_translated, X1,X2)
```

where `function_py_translated` would b the R equivalent of `function_py`.
I'm trying to use the rpy2 module, and for a simple function, I could make a working case:

```
import rpy2.rinterface as ri
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
sensitivity = importr('sensitivity')

radd = ri.baseenv.get('+')
def costfun(X):
    a = X[0]
    b = X[1]
    return(radd(a,b))

costfunr=ri.rternalize(costfun)
X1 = robjects.r('data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2*1000), nrow = 1000))')
X2 = robjects.r('data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2*1000), nrow = 1000))')

sobinde = sensitivity.sobol(costfunr,X1,X2)
print(sobinde.__getitem__(11))
```

The main problem is that I had to redefine the "+". Is there a way to work around this ? Being able to pass an arbitrary function without prior transformation ? The function I want to analyze is much more complicated.
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: I'm working now the other way around, by calling my python function from the R environment, with the package `rPython`. It is easier this way